# Is it possible to digitally sign and verify the signature without using a certificate?

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I've digitally signed data with certificates many times in different projects but never without a certificate.  I have the need to create and verify a signature that never expires.  Is there a way (c#) to digitally sign data without certificates?

Comment: The certificate provides the encryption key so you would need a key.  The key can come from anyplace and in any format.

Answer (score 2):

Digital Signing and verification may be done using just Private key and Public key pair and does not require Certificate. Certificate is nothing but public key along with owner's information such as Name, Organization, State, Country, etc signed by some trusted authority (called CA - Certifying Authority) using his private key.

For creating signature for PDF documents, that never expires, there is a concept of LTV (Long Term Validation). You may search for PDF LTV  Signature and you would be able to find lot of reference material.